# Joomla install stuck

Tags: jquery, joomla, installation, joomla3.4

I'm trying to install latest Joomla (3.4.4) on a new host. Copied all files to server, fired up browser and I get the first install screen. However the box where you can select site online/offline is not visible and this results in next button not working.

When I look in Chrome devtools I can see 5 errors that all say :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.
```

I've never had this before. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Thanks in advance, cheers,
Peter

Comment: Did you check if the jQuery library is actually loaded ?

Comment: Check the file ownership and the file permissions.

Comment: Try to completely clear your browser cache.